# Add arrays of different dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to add two arrays of different dimensions. Array A has shape (20,2,2,2,2,3) and array B has shape (20). Currently, I am using np.newaxis 5 times, so B gets the same shape as A and then I add them. In my actual code A is much bigger and this forces me to write np.newaxis many times. Is there a way to avoid repeating the np.newaxis and just tell python to give B the same shape as A?

```
A = np.zeros([20,2,2,2,2,3])
B = np.arange(1,21)
B = B[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis,np.newaxis,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
C = A + B
```

Comment: why don't you use Panda for work with DataFrames: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: @SerhiiMatvienko why would you use pandas for this problem?

Comment: @SerhiiMatvienko, `pandas` dataframes are 2d.  The OP example is 6d!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are broadcasting, this will work:

```
A= np.zeros([20,2,2,2,2,3])
B = np.arange(1,21)
B = B.reshape([20,1,1,1,1,1]) 
C = A + B
```

In a more dynamic way:

```
shape_a = [20,2,2,2,2,3]
A= np.zeros(shape_a)
B = np.arange(1,21)
shape_b = [shape_a[0]] +(len(shape_a)-1)*[1]
B = B.reshape(shape_b) 
C = A + B
```

With no broadcasting:

```
A = np.zeros([20,2,2,2,2,3])
B = np.arange(1,21)
C = A.copy()
C[:,0,0,0,0,0] += B
```

And if you don't care about A, just the result:

```
C = np.zeros([20,2,2,2,2,3])
B = np.arange(1,21)
C[:,0,0,0,0,0] += B
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is broadcasting to the number of dimensions of `A`, but if you look carefully, this operation you did does not make `B` have the same shape as `A`. Indeed they are still different:

```
>>> B[:, None, None, None, None, None].shape
(20, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

So this is basically applying [`np.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) consequently five times. An alternative way is to reshape the array with extra singletons:

```
>>> B.reshape((-1, *(1,)*(A.ndim-1))).shape
(20, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Which will reshape `(*,)` to `(*, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`.
This has the same effect as placing the `np.newaxis` manually.

Comment: `expand_dims` now takes a tuple, so `np.expand_dims(B,tuple(range(1,5)))` works.  Under the covers `expand_dims` just builds a `shape` as you do, and applies `reshape`.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can also do:

```
C = (A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1) + B[:,None]).reshape(A.shape)
```

Or swap the common axis to the end:

```
C = (A.swapaxes(0,-1) + B).swapaxes(0,-1)
```