# Calculus of two 2D arrays on different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two 2D arrays which I have to subtract, but not on the same dimension, and the arrays have different sizes. If I understood correctly there is something called broadcasting to do what I need and I think this post ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616936/add-arrays-of-different-dimensions)) shows everything needed to do it, but I have difficulties applying it to my problem, and moreover, there might be a more direct way then what I thought of so far.

### The Problem

Here is the general logic of the problem (illustrated below, apologies for black font if you are in dark mode): I've got two arrays, currently both on the same dimensions, on which they are of different size in rows (m and n rows). In their current shape, they only match in columns and I want to subtract every value of one array by every value of the other array column-wise.

[image]

I don't know which functions and operations can and should be done to efficiently do this without looping. I currently have a loop in place to do this, but the data I'm dealing with here is so large that it takes +12 minutes to complete.

### My Idea

I thought I might be able to first (1) transpose the first array onto different dimensions and then (2) repeat it by the number of rows of the other array, in order to get a `m*n*500` array when concatenated.

[image]

I then do the same for for the second array, just for different dimensions and repeat it by the number of what were previously the rows of the other array. Then when concatenated they should have the same size.

[image]

Then, finally, I would be able to simply subtract the two array from one another without any dimension conflicts.

[image]

### Code Example

Code-wise there is really not much to show here. Currently I'm looping through the rows of one of the arrays and then transpose it before using it in subtraction.

```
self.C = [] # list to hold the resulting arrays
for i in range(self.A.shape[0]): # loop over rows
   A = pd.DataFrame(self.A.iloc[i, :]).T
   C = pd.DataFrame(self.B.to_numpy() - A.to_numpy(), index=self.index)
   self.C.append((self.A.index[i], C))
```

The result is not even a 3D array but a list of tuples containing the indices and 2D arrays.

### The Ask

As already mentioned above, I don't know how to do this in numpy and I have difficulties applying answers from similar questions to my problem. I'd appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Typically questions like this are easiest to explain and answer when the arrays have small and mixed dimensions.  Instead of all dimensions being 500, think about arrays with shape (2,3,4), and (3,4) etc.  Then the `broadcasting` becomes easier to visualize.

Comment: Not all dimensions are 500, only one is, but for both arrays. So both arrays are 2D with 500 columns but different number of rows. In the first image, I indicated the number of rows with `m` and `n` for the two different arrays

Comment: Looping on a dataframe is slower than looping on an array.  Frames have all this row and column index baggage.  Can't you write the loop with (m,500) and (n,500) arrays?

Comment: If `A` is (m,k) and `B` is (n,k), then `A[:,None,:] - B[None,:,:]` should be (m,n,k).  Indexing with `None/newaxis` adds a size 1 dimension, which can then be "adjusted" to match the other arrays shape.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I understood that the answer below follows this logic and I'll try it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: See [hpaulj's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75714609/calculus-of-two-2d-arrays-on-different-dimensions#comment133568570_75714609).

---

You are correct that broadcasting is the solution! In fact, your visual representation of repeating arrays is exactly how the [numpy guide on broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) visualizes the technique.

In your case, let's say you start with two arrays `A` and `B` (which I've interpreted from your beautiful visuals):

```
A.shape == (500, M, 1)
B.shape == (500, N, 1)
```

and your output `C` should have shape:

```
C.shape == (M, N, 500)
```

that is to say, we should subtract every length `500` subarray in `B` (of which there are `N`) from every length 500 subarray in `A` (of which there are `M`).

In order to accomplish your use case, we would want array `A` to be "repeated" or "stacked" or "broadcasted" `N` times, and array `B` `M` times. The rules for broadcasting dictate that in some calculation between two arrays, the shapes of the arrays are right-aligned and any size 1 axes are broadcasted to be the same length as the axis in the other array. More info in the above linked guide.

In that sense:

```
shape (M, 1, 500) with
shape (1, N, 500)
================= would broadcast to
shape (M, N, 500)
```

which is exactly as required!

As such, we only need to "shuffle" or "permute" or "reorder" or "transpose" (all terms I've heard for reordering the axes of an array) the axes of your input arrays to broadcast to the required shape. You can do that in numpy using [`np.ndarray.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html). An example:

```
>>> M, N = 300, 100
>>> A = np.random.rand(500, M, 1)
>>> B = np.random.rand(500, N, 1)

>>> A.shape
(500, 300, 1)
>>> A.transpose(1, 2, 0).shape
(300, 1, 500)
>>> B.shape
(500, 100, 1)
>>> B.transpose(2, 1, 0).shape
(1, 100, 500)
```

Putting it together in a single piece of code:

```
import numpy as np

M, N = 300, 100
A = np.random.rand(500, M, 1)
B = np.random.rand(500, N, 1)

C = A.transpose(1, 2, 0) - B.transpose(2, 1, 0)
# C.shape == (M, N, 500)
```

---

One thing to note is that it is a lot more common to store arrays without any size 1 axes, and only introduce them when needed for broadcasting. For instance, you might start with:

```
A.shape == (M, 500)
B.shape == (N, 500)
```

which seems to me to be the most natural way to store your data. Now, to facilitate broadcasting, you'll have to introduce the size 1 axes yourself. Do this in such a way that between arrays `A` and `B` the size 500 axes are aligned, and the size `M` and `N` axes align with new size 1 axes.

Numpy provides various ways to do this, such as via [`np.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) or even [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), but the most popular way (especially when used to facilitate broadcasting as far as I've seen) is to index with [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) or equivalently `None`. This behavior is described in the [indexing guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#dimensional-indexing-tools).

Your code might then look like:

```
import numpy as np

M, N = 300, 100
A = np.random.rand(M, 500)
B = np.random.rand(N, 500)

C = A[:, None, :] - B[None, :, :]
# A[:, None, :].shape == (M, 1, 500)
# B[None, :, :].shape == (1, N, 500)
# C.shape == (M, N, 500)
```

This seems to me the most natural axis ordering for `C`, but you could of course reorder the axes of `C` afterward with `C = C.transpose(...)`.